# Retrieve log pattern via awk

Tags: regex, awk

I would like to retrieve from the following logs the date, the 5 URI length, the ab and cde:

```
10.10.10.10 - - [26/Oct/2020:19:50:13 +0000] "GET /five/six/seven/eight/nine/en?from=1603738800&to=1603785600ncludedInRange=false HTTP/1.1" 200 255441 "-" "Opera com.test.super/1.10.4;11072 (Linux;Neon KNWWWfj;0,02.2)" "10.10.10.10""f799b6b9-747f-4f22-a1bf-4b7de885fc60""-" "-" "-" "-"ab=0.110 cde=0.102
11.1.1.1 - - [26/Oct/2020:19:50:14 +0000] "GET /one/two/three/four/five/en HTTP/1.1" 200 2832 "-" "Opera com.test.super/1.10.4;11072 (Linux;Neon KNWWWfj;0,02.2)" "11.1.1.1""19a8ee3c-9cb3-4ba6-9732-eb4923601e92""-" "-" "-" "-"ab=0.111 cde=0.112
```

e.g.

```
26/Oct/2020:19:50:13 /five/six/seven/eight/nine ab=0.110 cde=0.102
```

I have tried the following command, but I get only a part of it. Can you please help?

```
awk '{print $4 "\t" $7 "\t" $(NF-1),"\t",$NF}' |sed 's/"-"//g'
```

Comment: Why is there no output for second line?

Comment: You and the poster at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616438/133219 should talk as you're both parsing very similar input files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[][[:space:]"]+' -v OFS='\t' '{match($7,"(/[^/]*){5}"); print $4, substr($7,1,RLENGTH), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
26/Oct/2020:19:50:13    /five/six/seven/eight/nine      ab=0.110        cde=0.102
26/Oct/2020:19:50:14    /one/two/three/four/five        ab=0.111        cde=0.112
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ed Morton, but setting FS in 5 parts:

```
$ awk -v FS='[[]|\\+[[:digit:]]+[]]|GET |/en|"+-"' '{print $2,$4,$NF}' file
26/Oct/2020:19:50:13  /five/six/seven/eight/nine ab=0.110 cde=0.102
26/Oct/2020:19:50:14  /one/two/three/four/five ab=0.111 cde=0.112
```

Updated.
Thanks to @Ed Morton.

Comment: In shell you should always use single quotes around strings and scripts unless you NEED double quotes to make the shell interpret it, e.g. for globbing, filename expansion, variable expansion, etc. If you follow that rule it'll make all your code more concise and more robust. In this case you won't need nearly as many backslashes in your `FS` declaration - right now you're asking the shell to interpret the string in `-v FS"..."` by surrounding it in double quotes and then escaping everything in it to stop the shell from interpreting it which makes no sense, just do `-v FS='...'` or `-F'...'`.

Comment: There's also no reason to put `-` or `"` inside a bracket expression or escape `/` in a dynamic regexp - they're all already literal chars. So idk if the code's right or wrong in general but I think all you need to specify that FS is `-F '[[]|\+[[:digit:]]+[]]|GET |/en|"+-"'`

Comment: @Ed Morton. Yes, I see, but is there specific documentation or a guide that includes a correct use of the syntactic peculiarities of regexp in awk?   it would help.

Comment: awk just implements POSIX EREs, so see the POSIX standard, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04. Awk does allow computed regexps (made up from strings and/or variables) as well as literal regexps - that's documented in the awk standard and all man pages and just means you need to be aware it's parsed twice and so needs extra escapes. Some VERSIONS of awk have minor extensions to POSIX such as `\<` and `\>` word boundaries or `\s/\S` shorthand, e.g. GNU awk, so see the man page for that awk version for details. Otherwise there are no peculiarities.